# Realizar petición a datos json con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html5, json, angularjs

Estoy intentando mostrar unos datos realizando una petición con angularJS pero no me devuelve nada la pantalla principal. En este caso debería mostrar el título.

**index.html:**

```
 <div ng-controller="postController">
        <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <li>{{post.userID}}</li>
            <li>{{post.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**postController.html:**

```
myApp.controller("postController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function (response) {
        $scope.post=response.data;
    }
)}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código del **index.html**, la propiedad del controlador que va a recibir los datos, y a partir de la cual se van a generar las repeticiones con la directiva `ng-repeat` se llama `posts`:

```
<ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <!-- Contenido -->
</ul>
```

Pero en el codigo JS de tu controlador, esa propiedad que recibe los datos se llama `post`.

```
$http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function (response) {
    $scope.post = response.data; // Propiedad post
}
```

¿Solución? Simple: Cambia el nombre de la propiedad de tu controlador de `$scope.post` a `$scope.posts`.

```
myApp.controller("postController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function (response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
    }
)}]);
```

Adicional a ello: La API que estás consumiendo devuelve registros con propiedad `userId`, no `userID`. Si quieres que se muestre esa información, en el primer elemento `<li>` anidado en el elemento `<ul>`, tienes que cambiar el `{{post.userID}}` por `{{post.userId}}`.

Lo puedes ver en acción en el siguiente snippet.

```js
/* Modelo */
let myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("postController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function (response) {
        $scope.posts=response.data;
    }
)}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="postController">
        <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <li>{{post.userId}}</li>
            <li>{{post.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```